# Mypy raises syntax error with pydrake stub

Tags: mypy, drake

When I try to run `mypy` in my project that has PyDrake as a depencency I get: `venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydrake/common/eigen_geometry.pyi:30: error: invalid syntax`

The line in questions is: `def cast[AutoDiffXd](self, *args, **kwargs) -> Any: ...`. I'm assuming this has something to do with PyDrake's custom templating system. How can I make MyPy and PyDrake play nice?

**Environment Info**

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Python version: 3.9.16
- MyPy version: 0.991
- Drake version: 1.11.0

Comment: This **is** invalid python syntax, `mypy` shouldn't handle it. You should submit a PR fixing this. Perhaps authors intended to declare `AutoDiffXd` as a type variable, but the whole line makes no sense even with horrible [PEP695](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/#summary-examples), because this type variable is not used in the signature. Also there are no `.pyi` files in repo you linked, please adjust the link (or are they auto-generated and not present in VC?)

Comment: @SUTerliakov they are indeed autogenerated. To understand why this syntax is here you may see https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/bindings/pydrake/common/cpp_template.py. I haven't looked deeply in it but I suspect some unconventional things have been done to make this work. The TLDR is that they have added a templating mechanism. Btw I expect someone from the Drake team to pick this up as Stackoverflow seems to be their preferred forum for getting help.

Comment: I just mean that the `.pyi` code above is not a valid python code, and `.pyi` stubs have the same syntax, so they certainly have some bug in implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the current version of Drake (v1.12.0), we unfortunately do not support Mypy.  The purpose of the `*.pyi` files as of today is solely to enable VSCode suggestion auto-complete.

We didn't have a central issue tracking this, so I've [filed a new one](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/18580).  Hopefully we can remove the syntax errors down the road.

The only work-around I know of for today is to delete the `*.pyi` files if you use Mypy.